# WAMP: failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Tags: wamp, php

I'm trying to upload a file using PHP. My HTML page with the form is stored at

```
C:\wamp\www\myproject\upload.html
```

PHP page is

```
 C:\wamp\www\myproject\upload.php,
```

and the file I'm trying to upload is

```
C:\wamp\www\myproject\openoffice.txt.
```

When I try to upload the file, I get the following error:

> **Warning**: move_uploaded_file(/uploads/openoffice.txt) [function.move-uploaded-file]: failed to open stream: No such file or
>   directory in C:\wamp\www\myproject\upload.php on line 40
>
> **Warning**: move_uploaded_file() [function.move-uploaded-file]: Unable to move 'C:\wamp\tmp\phpF66A.tmp' to '/uploads/openoffice.txt'
>   in C:\wamp\www\myproject\upload.php on line 40 Problem: could not move
>   file to destination directory

Here are lines 40-43 of upload.php:

```
if (!move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $upfile)) {
    echo 'Problem: could not move file to destination directory';
    exit;
}
```

The fact that it's looking in upload.php instead of the folder that it's in makes me wonder whether it's a server error or an issue with my PHP.

I Googled and got [this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php#95084) advice but I don't know if it's the right advice, or how to implement it. Help?

Comment: One often runs into this error, and to quickly troubleshoot it, follow these steps : https://stackoverflow.com/a/36577021/2873507

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be supplying a file system path for `$upFile`, not a web based path. try using the full system path to you your uploads directory like `C:\path\to\uploads\openoffice.txt`. Unless of course youre actually trying to place the file in `C:\uploads`...

Comment: There is now a troubleshooting checklist for this frequent error here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/36577021/2873507

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
$imgName = time();
$imgPath = BASEPATH."../uploads/".$imgName;
$image = base_url().'uploads/'.$imgName;
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],$imgPath.".jpg");
$imageNew =$imgName;
```

Where uploads is the folder name just rename it with your folder name or make your folder as name it as uploads. Its working code.

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Give your '/uploads/' folder where you are going to upload your file. 777 rights. Give full permission to that directory.